# How to get data from '$.post' in a localhost php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension that extracts DOMs from a website(not mine) and automates a button click with filling some inputs.

I made a local database which the extension will be extracting values from to fill the inputs, I could successfuly done that with xmlhttprequest that reads my php file from my content-script js file.

Now I want to send my php file that the button was clicked so it updates the database with new values. I tried $.post() but I can't get it with $_POST[];

content-script.js

```
setTimeout(
      function(){
        var finsih_div_found = $(dialog_div_found).find("div").get(12);
        var finish_button_found = $(finsih_div_found).find("button").get(2);
        finish_button_found.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true}))

        $.post('http://localhost:8012/extension-Oasis/php/getIntervenant.php', {button: 'Clicked'}, function(e){
            console.log("posted");
        });
},2000);
```

php file

```
$status = $_POST["button"]; //Gives an error of 'Undefined index: button'.
```

Please note that the website is not mine I don't have nor the back end nor the front end nor its API's. I just want to automate a button click that's done  regularly.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @Script47 no it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you called your PHP file directly? Then it is a HTTP GET request and therefore $_POST['button'] throws and 'Undefined index: button' error. In other words, you can only access the button value via $_POST[] if you use your jQuery $.post to do so.

```
   $.post('http://localhost:8012/extension-Oasis/php/getIntervenant.php', {button: 'Clicked'}, function(e){
        console.log(e); // log everything that is echoed in PHP file to browser's console
    });
```

In your PHP file, add a `echo $status;` in the last line.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. You can work with the value of `$status` in your PHP file now. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Actually no, I still have $status as undefined index on my php file and I need it to be 'clicked' instead so I can work with it. clicked is only shown in my js file.

Comment: Because your JS file is doing the actual POST. If you enter the URL of your PHP fiel in the browser, your browser will do an HTTP GET requests and therefore `$_POST` is empty. For a short but very precise explanation of HTTP methods look at [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).
In other words, you will always get this error if you call the PHP file directly via your browser because it doesn't "remembers" the value of $_POST['button'] from your last call. You have only access to the results of the PHP file in the JavaScript function.

Comment: Well the question is how do I let my php file know the button was clicked, not the js file.

Comment: Your PHP file knows it when called via `$.post` and returns the result of its execution properly back to the callback function of `$.post`. This is the normal behavior and unless you write your `$status` to a file or database in the PHP file, you are not able to know if the button was clicked when calling your PHP file again. You wrote that you have a local database available. You could add an entry to a table in this database every time the button was clicked (= PHP file was executed via POST) including for example a timestamp.

Comment: So this is not practical ? 
```
$status = $_POST["button"];
    if($status == "Clicked"){
      echo "test";
    }
```

Comment: This will output "test" if you call the PHP file via a POST request. In your code, this is the case inside of the callback function of the `$.post()` call. If you execute your JavaScript code know you will see a "test" in the console of your browser. If you open the PHP file directly in your browser (HTTP GET), you will still see the same error message. HTTP doesn't saves your current state. Without further tools, you have to handle every request as if it was your first one, i.e. send every data you need every time you make an HTTP call.

Comment: Would you please give more information on how I can get the button was clicked without php, cause I need this to be synchronous, and fast. cause the website reloads after every button click.

Comment: You can just add a click event to the button:
`var finish_button_found = $(finish_div_found ).find("button").get(2);` and `$(finish_button_found).on('click', function(e) { doWhatEver(); });` When capturing the click event, you can even prevent the page from doing what it would normally when clicking a button by using [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp).

Be aware of your typo in `finSIH_div_found` when copying my code proposal.